# Undefined Error when looking in Debug, trying to create DIV

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute the javascript below and I am getting an undefined error. I am just trying to create a div with some text and place it before a span tag when the page loads.. I could be totally off base with my code though:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function MMinsertPhoneinheader() {
     var div = document.createElement('div');
     div.innerHTML = ("<span> <p> Get Detailed Pricing </p> <br> <p> <b> (866)682-7927 </b></p> </span>");
     div.setAttribute('class', 'cust');
     document.getElementsByTagName('span')[5].appendChild(div);
     break;
};
MMinsertPhoneinheader();
</script>
```

Any help would be life saving. Sorry for the noob question. Thanks!

Here is the new code:

```
<script language="javascript">
function MMinsertPhoneinheader() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = ("<span> <p> Get Detailed Pricing </p> <br> <p> <b> (866)682-7927 </b></p> </span>");
   div.setAttribute('class', 'cust');
   document.querySelector(".toplinks").appendChild(div);
 };
MMinsertPhoneinheader();
</script>
```

I am getting the Syntax Error on line 3.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
```

Comment: What's the `break` there for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the break statement. That's causing your problem.

Also, I'd recommend using document.querySelector rather than your getElementsByTagName('span')[5].

That's brittle. With document.querySelector(), you can just use a css selector.

Comment: @GeuisThanks for your answer! I did the above and now I am getting a syntax error?

Comment: Share your modified code, details about the syntax error, what line, etc.

Comment: Works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/dtb2p/ I'm concerned about your script tag though. You don't have to specify a type. Just do <script>

Comment: it is now working for me as well. I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help, thanks.